# Google Maps is not working in BB OS 7

Tags: google-maps, blackberry

I have been doing a project in which I need to show the route to a particular location from my current location on a Google map. What I am currently doing is, I am appending source and destination latitudes and longitudes as parameters to Google maps URL (http://maps.google.com/?saddr=43.6775,-80.7339&daddr=34.5008311,-117.1858759&output=embed) and showing it on a BlackBerry browser. It was working fine for my 9800 Torch device and all of the OS 6 devices.

But when I tested on 9850 (OS 7) device, the map was not loading. Just a Google logo at the bottom with  zoom in and out buttons, but it wasn't working either. When I tested on other OS 7 simulators, I saw the same problem in all models. Does anyone having the same problem? Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: No idea why, but I get the same thing on a 9810 with OS 7.1

Comment: None has any answer on why is it happening? Please help me by providing some valid inputs :(

Comment: Blackberry 6 is [supported](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#browsersupport). Blackberry 7 is not.