# Blackberry Maps doesn't work on OS 7

Tags: blackberry, maps

I have a simple code that loads BB Maps for a specific latitude and longitude. This works just fine in BB 9700 with OS5 but it didn't work when I used four other devices that has OS 7. I have used same SIM card for the testing.

Desktop Manager is showing the BB Maps is installed. I have also tried buy reinstalling OS 7 and BB Maps in one of the 4 devices but no luck.

I would really appriciate If anybody could help me finding the solution. Thanks in advance.

```
package mypackage;

import javax.microedition.location.Coordinates;
import javax.microedition.location.Location;

import net.rim.device.api.lbs.MapField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Keypad;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

/**
 * A class extending the MainScreen class, which provides default standard
 * behavior for BlackBerry GUI applications.
 */
public final class BBMapsScreen extends MainScreen {
    /**
     * Creates a new MyScreen object
     */

    Location location = null;
    MapField mapField;

    public BBMapsScreen() {
        setTitle( "BB Maps test" );

        double latitude = 45.42349;
        double longitude = -75.69793;
        Coordinates mCoordinates = new Coordinates( latitude, longitude, 0 );

        mapField = new MapField();
        mapField.moveTo( mCoordinates );

        add( mapField );
    }
}
```

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053531/google-maps-is-not-working-in-bb-os-7

Comment: When swapping the SIM card to the other devices, have you checked the Service Book to ensure that all of the provisioning has been pushed down to the device before you test your code?

Comment: Its not related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053531/google-maps-is-not-working-in-bb-os-7. I am not using google maps.